# Хранение данных в БД Андроид

Tags: android, база-данных

У Андроид приложения есть основной сервер, к которому подключена БД и периодически приложение синхронизирует данные с этим сервером-бд. Но в случае офлайн доступа, некоторые функции приложения также должны работать, поэтому необходимо хранить некоторые данные и локально.

**Собственно вопросы:**

1. Как обычно хранят данные локально и удаленно с учетом синхронизации? В интернете встречаю связки SQLite + Room и Firebase. Объясните пожалуйста, какие подходы используются?
2. Не могу понять процесс синхронизации между локальной и удаленной БД. Как я понимаю, локальная БД и удаленная не будут полностью совпадать. Как именно происходит сравнение?

Я обычно пишу бэк на Golang+Postgres. А вот с андроидом в разработке не встречался и поэтому не могу понять базовые вещи хранения и синхронизации данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом данные хранить на устройстве можно тремя способами:

- SharedPreference для простых данных.
- База данных. Для хранения более сложных объектов.
- Сохранять в файл. Если вам необходимо эти данные каким-либо образом шарить или оставлять на устройстве после удаления приложения.

Как это синхронизировать? Это зависит от того, каких целей вы хотите достичь. В можете прогонять все данные через БД или же сохранять только избранные задачи.

Синхронизация тоже лежит на вас. Да они могут быть рассинхронизированы с сервером, если к примеру устройство долго не было подключено к сети. Показывать ли их пользователю зависит от вашего приложения. Например можно показать пользователю фотки в его коллекции Google Photos, но показывать неактуальный счет в банковском приложении наверное не стоит.

Как это происходит обычно? Вы получаете данные от сервера и сохраняете их в БД, а потом уже само приложение дергает их из базы данных. Если вы что-то меняете вы должны это синхронно сохранять на сервер и в БД.

Тут очень трудно привести какие-то примеры, потому что все зависит от ваших задач. Надеюсь я смог вам немного помочь.

Comment: Да, весьма полезный ответ. Спасибо.

Возьмем стандартный пример - Список задач на каждый день.
Базовые вещи синхронизации мне практически понятны:

1) Если пишем локально, то добавляем их в очередь для отправки на сервер
2) Раз в N минут или при OnCreate дергаем удаленную БД и проверяем состояние. 

У меня скорее вопрос как именно сравнивать БД. Возьмем тот же пример с ToDo на каждый день. Я же не буду проверять всю таблицу  tasks целиком. То есть нужно делать оптимизации вроже updated_at столбца. Мне интересно, есть ли общепринятые подходы или библиотеки для этого или все вручную?

Comment: Для работы с БД есть Room это решение от  Google и пожалуй самое лучшее решение. Так же есть ORMLite и др. Для работы с сетью есть Retrofit это уже почти как часть фреймворка Android. Ее используют почти везде. А вот организовывать синхронизацию это уже ручками.

Comment: И второй непонятный момент насчет пункта 1 моего предыдущего комментария.
В каких именно случаях (кроме явного запроса от пользователя) стоит делать синхронизацию и как обрабатывать ситуации если упала сеть или пользователь закрыл приложение? Синхронизация в такие моменты просто прерывается?

То есть основной вопрос про архитектуру синхронизации и очереди обновления.
Я пока не могу найти точку поиска, чтобы начать гуглить. Все приложение на MVP. Данные получаются через DataProvider. Приложение разделено на 3 модуля: UI, Data (Хранение и получение данных), Domain (бизнес логика).

Comment: Ну все зависит от задач. Но вы можете например всякий раз при старте приложения проверять актуальность данных. Например можно вообще пользователю показывать данные ТОЛЬКО из БД, а в фоне подгружать данные из сети.  А после подгрузки данных оповещать пользователей БД о том, что надо обновить данные. Или вообще подписаться на изменения в БД и данные сами будут подтягиваться всякий раз когда там что-то меняется. Для этого можно использовать RX Java или  LiveData

Comment: Если падает сеть тут есть несколько вариантов. Если ваше приложение может работать без сети, вы можете показывать дефолтные или ранее загруженные данные. Если же ваше приложение не имеет смысле без интернета, то пожалуй просто уведомление пользователю о том, что мол сорян, но у тебя нет интернета. Тут ничего не поделаешь

Comment: А если взять ваш пример синхронизации в фоне при старте приложения, то как бы вы реализовывали синхронизацию таблицы tasks с удаленным бэкендом?
В локальной таблице могу менять абсолютно любые данные и нужно это делать как то оптимизированно без проверки всей таблицы целиком. 

Пока приходит на ум только поле is_sync, которые ставится в false при каждом изменении данных локально и ставится в true, сразу после успешной синхронизации записи.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108511/discussion-between-sergei-buvaka-and--).